# String row-index in pd.read_csv causes error "The label [1] is not in the [index]"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing

I am importing a CSV into a pandas dataframe.  When I am do this, I am setting the index column to 0, which is the Index listed (0 to 10).  I am getting the error Key Error: the label [1] is not in the [index].

I've checked the data multiple times to make sure that the first column is the list of numbers.  Any hints on how I can fix this?

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import random
import math


#USER VARIABLES

#GAME VARIABLES

Passengers = 500

data = pd.read_csv("Problem2/data.csv", index_col=0)
print(data)

obs = len(data)

data["A"] = 0
data["B"] = 0
data["U"] = 0


for row in range(1,obs+1, 1):

    A = 0
    B = 0
    U = 0

    for i in range(1, Passengers + 1, 1):

        if data.loc[row, i] == "A":
            A += 1
        elif data.loc[row, i] == "B":
            B += 1
        else:
            U += 1


    data.loc[row, "A"] = A
    data.loc[row, "B"] = B
    data.loc[row, "U"] = U

ServiceLevels = range(170, 210,1)
for level in ServiceLevels:
    print(str(level) + " " + str(len(data[((data.A <= level))])/obs))
```

Dataset = https://github.com/deacons2016/SimulationModels/blob/master/Exam1/Problem2/data.csv

Comment: That CSV file has 503 columns, is 14.5 MB and so large that github refuses to show a preview(!). Please reduce your examples to the minimum size needed to repro the issue, in future.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to read index data as string with pandas.read\_csv()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058435/how-to-read-index-data-as-string-with-pandas-read-csv) This question has been asked tons of times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast columns with `str` in your for.

```
In[60]: data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Desktop/data.csv', sep = ',', index_col = [0])

In[61]: obs = len(data)

In[62]: data["A"] = 0
        data["B"] = 0
        data["U"] = 0

In[63]: Passengers = 500

In[64]: for row in range(1,obs+1):
            print row
            A = 0
            B = 0
            U = 0
            for i in range(1, Passengers + 1, 1):
                if data.loc[row, str(i)] == "A":
                    A += 1
                elif data.loc[row, str(i)] == "B":
                    B += 1
                else:
                    U += 1
            data.loc[row, "A"] = A
            data.loc[row, "B"] = B
            data.loc[row, "U"] = U
1
.
.
10
```

A shortest way to do that :

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Desktop/data.csv', sep = ',', index_col = [0])

cols = data.columns
data['A'] = (data[cols] == 'A').astype(int).sum(axis=1)
data['B'] = (data[cols] == 'B').astype(int).sum(axis=1)
data['U'] = (data[cols] == 'U').astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you!   I have been stuck on that.

Comment: @JeremyLewallen: I added a shortest way to do that in 4 lines :)

Comment: Thanks.   I didn't know that was possible. :)

Comment: No you don't need to apply `str()` every time you look up the index with a number. You just make the index a string column once and for all at csv-read-time. See [How to read index data as string with pandas.read_csv()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058435/how-to-read-index-data-as-string-with-pandas-read-csv) with `read_csv(index_col = ...) and set its dtype.