# replacing null value with 0 with special condition every other row

Tags: python, pandas

This is the following subset of a dataset:

```
A  B    C         D         R        sentence              ADR1         ADR2     
112 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1    lack of good feeling.     good        feeling
113 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1                               1
115 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2    Feel disconnected        disconnected   feel    
116 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2                                             0
118 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1    Weight gain               gain         
119 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1                                1
```

In column ADR1 and ADR2, for each word, there should be 1 or 0 in the row blow it. if the value is missing, I need to replace it with "0". This is the output:

```
A  B    C         D         R        sentence              ADR1         ADR2     
112 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1    lack of good feeling.     good        feeling
113 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1                               1             0
115 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2    Feel disconnected        disconnected   feel    
116 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2                                 0            0
118 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1    Weight gain               gain         
119 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1                                1
```

I tried

```
df[ADR1].fillna(0, inplace=True) and df[ADR2].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

but this code produce the following df, which is not wanted

```
 A  B    C         D         R        sentence              ADR1         ADR2     
112 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1    lack of good feeling.     good        feeling
    113 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1                               1        0
    115 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2    Feel disconnected        disconnected   feel                                                                 0
    116 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2                                             0
    118 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1    Weight gain               gain           0
    119 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1                                1            0
```

Comment: @open-Source, last row just have one word and it has 1 below it.  ADR2 for last row is null, so the row blow it is also null.

Comment: I realized later so, removed my previous comment, thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. SO is a place to get help with specific program coding issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to allow working on the data every other row at a time. Something like:

#### Code:

```
for col in ['ADR1', 'ADR2']:
    data = np.reshape(df[col].values, (-1, 2))
    need_fill = np.logical_and(data[:, 0] != '', data[:, 1] == '')
    data[np.where(need_fill),1] = 0
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    A   B   C   D             R  sentence              ADR1         ADR2     
    112 135 21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling  good         feeling
    113 135 21  EffexorXR.21  1                        1
    115 136 21  EffexorXR.21  2  Feel disconnected     disconnected feel    
    116 136 21  EffexorXR.21  2                                     0
    118 142 22  EffexorXR.22  1  Weight gain           gain         
    119 142 22  EffexorXR.22  1                        1"""),
                 header=1).fillna('')

print(df)
for col in ['ADR1', 'ADR2']:
    data = np.reshape(df[col].values, (-1, 2))
    need_fill = np.logical_and(data[:, 0] != '', data[:, 1] == '')
    data[np.where(need_fill),1] = 0
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
     A    B   C             D  R              sentence          ADR1     ADR2
0  112  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling          good  feeling
1  113  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1                                   1         
2  115  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2     Feel disconnected  disconnected     feel
3  116  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2                                            0
4  118  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1           Weight gain          gain         
5  119  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1                                   1         

     A    B   C             D  R              sentence          ADR1     ADR2
0  112  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling          good  feeling
1  113  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1                                   1        0
2  115  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2     Feel disconnected  disconnected     feel
3  116  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2                                   0        0
4  118  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1           Weight gain          gain         
5  119  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1                                   1
```

Comment: thank you. If I have more than 2 columns for ADR, I just need to add it to the list of  ['ADR1', 'ADR2'], and other part of the code does not change. Yes ?

Comment: Give it a try.  If you copy and paste the section under *Test Code*, it is standalone.  Rename the column in the test data, and then try your suggested change and see if it still works.

Comment: I copied your code, but it did not work. My data frame has just 2 column of ADR1 and ADR2 , any suggestion ?

Comment: I would need more than a simple *it does not work*.  What does it not do?

Comment: is there any place that I can upload a subset of my document that you can access to it ?

Comment: Thank you. Would you please answer this question, it is very similar to this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747810/replacing-nan-value-with-a-word-when-nan-is-not-repeated-in-two-consecutive-rows

Answer (score 1):

Other way you can try is to `iterate` through `rows` of `dataframe` for each `column` to check and check if next value is empty given the first value is not empty, then update the value to `0`:

```
col_list = ['ADR1', 'ADR2'] # columns to check
for column in col_list: # for each column go through each rows
    # however the step size is 2 at a time since current and next is checked
     for i in range(0, df.shape[0]-1, 2): 
        first_val = df.loc[i][column]
        next_val = df.loc[i+1][column]
        # check if given current not empty, is next empty
        if not first_val == '' and next_val  == '':
            df.loc[i+1, column] = 0 # update the value
```

Comment: it has the following error:  KeyError: 'the label [2] is not in the [index]', Do you know why ?

Comment: @Mary not sure, I did not get any error. on which line did it actually gave error in? Can you check if replacing `column` with `str(column)` works? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33590065/5916727

Comment: yes it solved. Would you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747230/replacing-missing-with-a-word-based-on-values-of-the-next-row-if-value-in-next

Comment: @Mary Great! do you mean adding `str(column)` helped or you found different solution? (*Just curious*) I will try to look into other question.

Comment: Yes, This is the link for other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747810/replacing-nan-value-with-a-word-when-nan-is-not-repeated-in-two-consecutive-rows